# Android WebView canGoBack always true

Tags: javascript, android, webview, back

I have a WebView that is loading social media pages. I have overridden the Back button to call the `goBack` method on the WebView until `canGoBack()` returns `false`. Then it calls `super.onBackPressed()`. The problem is that Twitter and YouTube use Javascript in such a way that `canGoBack()` returns `true` unless you tap the back button 4 times really quickly.

I've tried checking the original url with the current url, but the page has a different url than the one that gets passed in.

Does anyone know a way to have the back button call the WebView's `goBack` method until you are at the beginning, then call `super.onBackPressed`?

Comment: 6 years and still no 'real solution'

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but in my case the problem was that I, when overriding the WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), I checked if the url was the correct one, and if it was I was loading that url in my webView and returning false after that which shouldn't be done. So I just returned false and it started working correctly.
Hope I helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not ideal but you may track the navigation history manually by using an array (or just an integer to be increased and decreased) and push the current url into it every time it changes and pop the last url from it when you press the back button, and if the array is empty (or the integer is 0) you call `super.onBackPressed()`.
To execute code when the url changes, you can override the method `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` of the 
 `WebViewClient` ([link to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))).
This way the web pages' javascript can't interfere with how you handle the back button.

Comment: This solution will stuck if user click on Logout button on respective website. Now how will you track that back stack = 0 and not N number.

Comment: Logging out doesn't necessarily mean that the history stack needs to be reset. It depends on how you want your app to behave.